# Unable to get the Environment in .Net Core Application

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a .Net Core Application with Development, Release, and Staging environments. I want to choose a specific environment using Launch Settings but I always get Production. What am I missing here ?

Launch Settings:

```js
{
  "profiles": {
    "CoreService": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT ": "Development"
      },
      "remoteDebugEnabled": false
    }
  }
}
```

```js
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureLogging(loggerFactory =>
                {
                    loggerFactory.AddEventLog();
                    loggerFactory.AddEventSourceLogger();
                })
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                          .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

                    if (env.EnvironmentName.Contains("Development"))
                    {
                        var appAssembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(env.ApplicationName));
                        if (appAssembly != null)
                        {
                            config.AddUserSecrets(appAssembly, optional: true);
                        }
                    }

                    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();

                    if (args != null)
                    {
                        config.AddCommandLine(args);
                    }
                  
                })
```

Thank You.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to be using `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Tried ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT but no impact.

Comment: The settings that you set within `launchSettings.json` will be used when you run the .NET core application either from Visual Studio or by using .NET Core CLI. Can you share the full content of your `launchSettings.json` file and clarify more about how you are running your app?

Comment: It is most certainly ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT that you are looking for.  If you look at what CreateDefaultBuilder does [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.host.createdefaultbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) you'll notice it already adds the environment variables, so you have two environment variable providers which may be conflicting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space in the "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT " is causing the issue.